# Is Grandpa right? Another Grandpa mystery

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Grandpa likes Warren Buffet but not Bill Gates
>
> Grandpa likes Prince Harry but not Prince William
>
> Grandpa likes President McKinley but not President Clinton

Why is that?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the proper answer as correct.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"Is Grandpa *right*?"

> Yes! He IS "right"!

Because:

> He does not like LEFT-HANDED people.
>  He may have [sinistrophobia](http://common-phobias.com/sinistro/phobia.htm), a fear of left-handed people.
>
>  All the people he likes are right handed. Those he dislikes are "lefties".
>
>  [Bill Gates](http://time.com/4451303/international-left-handers-day-why-are-people-left-handed/), [Bill Clinton](http://www.govtech.com/question-of-the-day/Question-of-the-Day-for-02172015.html) and [Prince William](https://www.cbsnews.com/pictures/famous-lefties/2/) are all left handed.

Comment: Way to go Astrabee. Grandpa needs to remember that although they are Left Handed but they are always right!

Comment: Well that's fine, Grandpa. I guess I don't like you either...

Answer (score 20):

Your grandpa:

> Doesn't generally like people called "Bill". Bill is short for William, so *Bill* Gates, Prince *William* and President *Bill* Clinton all share that name.

I believe this is because:

> He loves money and the US economy! "Bills" represent outgoing money. But both H**arr**y and W**arr**en contain the letters "arr" which in financial terms refers to *accounting rate of return*, or profit.

The exception being:

> He "*prefers*" President *William* McKinley to *Bill* Clinton, possibly because given the choice of two presidents both called William he likes the one that goes by "Bill" less?
>
>  Or maybe he makes an exception for McKinley because of his famous "McKinley Tariff" which was supposed to boost the American economy by limiting foreign imports. Bill Clinton's economic policy was the opposite of McKinley's in this regard - he set up the North American Free Trade Agreement which promotes trade outside the USA. Also President McKinley had as Vice President *G**arr**et Hobart* who also has "arr" in his name.

Comment: You are missing a very simple fact

Comment: @DEEM Okay - one overarching fact? Am I on the right lines?

Comment: Every word of the puzzle tells you something? Right?

Comment: Even though I can see that htis is not the correct answer, the first part at least is a pretty convincing thing they all have in common. I would suggest that this would be even better riddle if such a coincidence was avoided.

Comment: J E That is the point. William or Bill on one side only would make it very obvious answer. So I put a William on the other side.

Answer (score 4):

Grandpa likes...

> Peoples whose initials are in Reverse Alphabetical Order.

Warren Buffet vs Bill Gates:

> W. (23rd letter) B. (2nd letter) vs B. (2nd letter) G. (7th letter)

Prince Harry vs Prince William

> P. (16) H. (8) vs P. (16) W. (23)

President McKinley vs President Clinton

> William McKinley vs Bill Clinton
>  W.MK. (23,13,11) vs B. C. (2,3)

So, he likes

> The alphabet to read from Right to Left

Comment: I thought this too, but why are the Princes' titles included but not the Presidents'?

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails Because a dynastic house doesn't *technically* have a surname?  They are "Prince Harry, Duke of Sussex, of the House of Windsor" and "Prince William, Duke of Cambridge, of the House of Windsor", not "Harry Windsor, Duke of Sussex" and "William Windsor, Duke of Cambridge".  Even then, you have the argument based on their Dukedom's - is it "William Windsor", or "William Cambridge"?  But, it's *definitely* "Bill Clinton, former President of the United States"

Comment: Then did he like him when he was President Clinton but dislike him when he switched back to Bill Clinton?

Comment: Both Harry Windsor + William Windsor and Harry Sussex + William Cambridge would clash with the concept, though.